# converting method to function?

Tags: scala

1) How is this construction called? Cannot google it.

2) Why it doesn't work? I expect message be printed.

```scala
class A {
  def m() {
    println("m()")
  }
}

object Main {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val fun = (_: A).m _
    fun(new A())
  }

}
```

Comment: It is called *partially applied function*, please, see http://blog.sanaulla.info/2010/12/25/partially-applied-functions-in-scala/ for details

Comment: That's a new one for me: `(_: A).m`

Comment: `(_: A).m` is `A => Unit` and `(_: A).m _` is `A => (() => Unit)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As om-nom-nom says, the conversion of methods to functions is called "partial application." It can be expressed explicitly by using underscore(s) as "arguments" to a method or automatically by the compiler when the available type information is sufficient for it to infer that a method name used in a place where a function is required can be partially applied to produce the required function.

Now, for your code. As written, the result of the call `fun(new A())` is a `Function1[Unit, Unit]`. You'd have to `apply` that function to get the `println` invoked

```
// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class A
defined module Main

scala> Main.main(Array())

scala> def doIt { val fun = (_: A).m _; fun(new A())() }
doIt: Unit

scala> doIt
m()
```